# Change data interval and add the average to the original data

Tags: python

I have a dataset that includes a country's temperature in 2020 and the projected temperature rise in 2050. I'm hoping to create a dataset that assumes the linear growth of temperature between 20201 and 2050 for this country. Take the sample `df` as an example. The temperature in 2020 for country A is 5 degree; by 2050, the temperature is projected to rise by 3 degree. In other words, the temperature would rise by 0.1 degree per year.

```
Country Temperature 2020    Temperature 2050
      A         5           3
```

The desired output is `df2`

```
Country Year    Temperature
    A   2020    5
    A   2021    5.1
    A   2022    5.2
```

I tried to use resample but it seems to only work for scenario when the frequency is within a year (month, quarter). I also tried interpolate. But neither works.

```
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start='20211231', end='20501231', freq='12MS'))
df2 = df.interpolate(method='linear')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def interpolate(df, start, stop):
    a = np.empty((stop - start, df.shape[0]))
    a[1:-1] = np.nan
    a[0] = df[f'Temperature {start}']
    a[-1] = df[f'Temperature {stop}']

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(a, index=pd.date_range(start=f'{start+1}', end=f'{stop+1}', freq='Y'))
    return df2.interpolate(method='linear')

df = pd.DataFrame([["A", 5, 3]], columns=["Country", f"Temperature 2020", f"Temperature 2050"])
df[f"Temperature 2050"] += df[f"Temperature 2020"]
print(interpolate(df, 2020, 2050))
```

This will output

```
2021-01-01  5.000000
2022-01-01  5.103448
2023-01-01  5.206897
2024-01-01  5.310345
2025-01-01  5.413793
2026-01-01  5.517241
2027-01-01  5.620690
2028-01-01  5.724138
2029-01-01  5.827586
2030-01-01  5.931034
2031-01-01  6.034483
2032-01-01  6.137931
2033-01-01  6.241379
2034-01-01  6.344828
2035-01-01  6.448276
2036-01-01  6.551724
2037-01-01  6.655172
2038-01-01  6.758621
2039-01-01  6.862069
2040-01-01  6.965517
2041-01-01  7.068966
2042-01-01  7.172414
2043-01-01  7.275862
2044-01-01  7.379310
2045-01-01  7.482759
2046-01-01  7.586207
2047-01-01  7.689655
2048-01-01  7.793103
2049-01-01  7.896552
2050-01-01  8.000000
```